# uninitialized constant Mail::Ruby19

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Hi there brilliant minds, ive encountered this when trying to run this code. Can't figure it out. Hope someone can help.

This is for "forgotten password" reset mail.

EDIT: I have tried restarting the app a few times. That is not whats causing the issue.

User model:

```
validations up here...

def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end

def send_password_reset
  generate_token(:password_reset_token)
  self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
  save!
  UserMailer.deliver_password_reset(self)
end
```

Password reset controller:

```
def create
  user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
  user.send_password_reset if user
  redirect_to signin_path, :notice => "Email sent with instructions."
end
```

user mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@mysite.com"

  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Eventalist - Password Reset.")
  end
end
```

error:

```
uninitialized constant Mail::Ruby19

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/models/user.rb:19:in `send_password_reset'
app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb:7:in `create'

This error occurred while loading the following files:
 mail
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What's on line number 1 of `app/mailers/user_mailer.rb`? From the error message, it seems to be a `require` statement that can't load the specified file.

Comment: line 1 class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
line 2     default from: "from@example.com"

Comment: Could you please edit the question, and include the full `app/mailers/user_mailer.rb` file please? Or at least the first few lines?

Comment: it seems to me that it could be some sort of bug. everything works fine up to the point where i try and use the mailer. if i comment out UserMailer.deliver_password_reset(self) it works (obviously without sending the email) :/

Comment: @TheoFelippe, shouldn't you use `UserMailer.password_reset(user).deliver` syntax?

Comment: It was a bug. For some reason when i generated the mailer, rails go lazy and forgot to dome some of the configuration that it normally does. It's all good now. thanks

Comment: @TheoFelippe - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

Per [Shamir K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1780238/shamir-k), the UserMailer syntax may be suspect. This is a fair observation -- note the source material used by the original poster here:

[RailsCast #274: Remember Me & Reset Password](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password)

That being said, the [original poster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1664133/theo-felippe) later clarified that his issue was the result of some missing configuration:

> It was a bug. For some reason when i generated the mailer, rails go lazy and forgot to dome some of the configuration that it normally does. It's all good now. thanks